# How to use input string, to call variable name in c++

Tags: variables, input, type-conversion

so I just have what seems like a rudimentary problem. 
But for some reason I can't wrap my mind around it.

So given the code:

```
int Red = 1;
int Blue = 2;
int Green = 3;

main (){
cout << "Enter your keyword";
cin >> str1;
```

If the user inputs the word Red, i want it to return the value of the variable "Red", without using an **if statement** for every variable (I have 200+ variables).

To be more specific:

If the user inputs Red, I want my program to read the first item in my array. To do that I need red to represent a number value.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No idea what you want. What does "call particular variables" mean?

Comment: Updated my explanation.

Comment: You can't do it, I'm afraid. You need to set up a structure that ties the variables to their names. You might use `std::map` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: Question misunderstood.

---

You cannot ref to a variable based on a string value.

But you can setup a list of structure who contain a combination of `key` and `value`. You should look at [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: I decided to go the if statement route for now. its just a few hundred copy pastes. Should only take 10 minutes to make all the adjustments. 
Meanwhile I will begin learning about maps. Thanks Arthur and Tony.

Comment: And unordered_map :)